# Error in blackbox xilinx system generator

Tags: matlab, vhdl, xilinx-ise, black-box

I use Xilinx system generator blocks in Matlab and i find the block black box wich can generate and simulate vhdl code. I programme a simple program in vhdl for port and,

```html
--import std_logic from the IEEE library
library ieee;
use ieee.std_logic_1164.all;

--ENTITY DECLARATION: name, inputs, outputs
entity andGate is                   
   port( A, B : in std_logic;
            F : out std_logic);
end andGate;

--FUNCTIONAL DESCRIPTION: how the AND Gate works
architecture func of andGate is 
begin
  F <= A and B;     
end func;
```

I simulate in xilinx with blackbox and i make simulation mode ISE Simulator because i use xilinx .

I apreciate any kind of help thanks :)

Comment: Could you be more clear on what your issue is?

Comment: Thanks fr your reply , i use blackbox from xilinx system generator on matlab but an erroe message ''Error reported by S-function 'sysgen' in 'essai1/Black Box':An internal error occurred in the Xilinx Blockset Library.''I don't know the reason my code in vhdl is posted  thankss how can i use blackbox ?? is there is any specificity thankss

Comment: This is mainly a statement, could you at least describe a problem you are trying to solve ?

Comment: Is there is anyone who used the block blackbox from matlab xilinx système generator  ??

Answer (score 0):

check your gateway in, you should select its output as Boolean

also, check the sampling time of the system, you should make all equal to 1

Comment: This could be a comment not a an answer. You can add more description to make it a good answer - [From Review](http://stackoverflow.com/review/late-answers/12348467)